# Default bottom placement not respected when using floating-ui autoPlacement()

Tags: floating-ui

I'm using [floating-ui with Vue](https://floating-ui.com/docs/vue) to make floating tooltips.

One feature of `floating-ui` is [autoPlacement()](https://floating-ui.com/docs/autoPlacement), where in real-time the floated element will dynamically re-position itself according to space available. E.g. if a tooltip occurs near the viewport edge, it will re-position itself to maintain visibility.

Everything works, however, **my "*tooltip-with-autoplacement*" seems to favor placement on the `right`** no matter how much surrounding space is available. I tested various combinations of margin/padding/width/height on the reference element and parent container.

Confirmed proper `bottom` placement *does* indeed work in other conditions (but none of these are ideal scenarios)...

1. Removing `autoPlacement()` completely; bottom works (as per
   default)
2. When the tooltip occurs at the top of the viewport,
   `autoPlacement()` successfully moves it to the bottom.
3. If I restrict placements in `autoPlacement()` options: `allowedPlacements: ['bottom', 'left']`

So AFAICT, bottom placement works just fine, I just want to strongly prefer it for `autoPlacement()`.

**QUESTION:** When using `autoPlacement()`, how can I reliably make the tooltip open towards the bottom (when given ample space)?

**CODE:**

```
import { useFloating, autoPlacement } from '@floating-ui/vue'

const referenceElement = ref()
const floatingElement = ref()
const { floatingStyles } = useFloating(
    referenceElement,
    floatingElement,
    {
        placement: 'bottom', // Necessary? Doing anyways.
        middleware: [
            autoPlacement()
        ]
    }
)
```